# Direction for 2-dimensional vector only in one axis

Tags: game-physics, physics-engine

I'm working on a small physics engine and am hitting a dead end. What I'm trying to do is cast a ray from the origin of a quads' position (2-dimensional vector), to a direction based on its velocity. The quads' velocity is also a 2-dimensional vector.

To get the direction to cast the ray in, I do the following:

```
(quad.position + quad.velocity) - quad.position
```

This will return a 2-dimensional vector that can be used as a direction. The problem I'm facing is that when one of the axis or both is/are 0, there is no direction when doing the above math. As the result will have 0 in one of its axis (where there was no velocity).

The way I'm using this direction is by using this ray to check for collision between another quad. This can be done by calculating the exact "time" along the ray a hit occurs. I do this by having the position of the 2nd quad - the origin of the ray (the position of the 1st quad) / the ray direction. Obviously, when one of the axis of the direction is 0, I get a DivideByZero error.

I was wondering what I could do to fix this behaviour. I was to still do the ray casting, but as if it was infinite. Or in better words, do the ray casting, but in a straight line along the axis that had 0 as the direction. When I pass some arbitrary number like 0.00001, it all works, but the ray cast is slightly off the straight line I want it to go.

I've been looking online but can't seem to find anything useful.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing when you *divide* one vector by another, but I'm pretty sure that it's not a good way to check for collision.

Comment: It's something similar to this: https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-sphere-intersection

Comment: Following a YT, the source code can be found here: https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcPixelGameEngine/blob/master/Videos/OneLoneCoder_PGE_Rectangles.cpp The function RayVsRect in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- A vector has zero length only when **ALL** components are zero eg `{x:0, y:0, z:0}`.
- Only when a vector has zero length is its direction undefined.

The same applies to vectors in all dimensions 2D, 3D, 4D, ..., nD and even 1D vectors.

To get the length (magnitude) of a vector use [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)

eg

```
vec = {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}
length = (vec.x ^ 2 + vec.y ^ 2 + vec.z ^ 2) ^ 0.5
// AKA length = sqrt(vec.x * vec.x + vec.y * vec.y + vec.z * vec.z)

// in 2D
vec = {x: 1, y: 1}
length = (vec.x ^ 2 + vec.y ^ 2) ^ 0.5
```

If a vector has zero length then it can not intercept anything

```
vec = {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
if (vec.x == 0 && vec.y == 0 && vec.z == 0) { return NO_INTERCEPT }
```

The math you linked to, [in comments](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-sphere-intersection), will not result in a divide by zero if the vector has length eg `{x:0, y:1}` `length == 1` is true.

I suggest you have misinterpreted the math in the link.

Comment: After some exploration, you're 100% correct, that by getting the magnitude of a vector (length), I can use that to "steer" the ray.